# Django Update User via Update View

Tags: django

I'm using Django update view and when I send the id of the user I want to update
it is switching me from the current user that logged in to the one I want to change.

For example, I want to update the name and password of user X via User Y. When I go to the update view it switches me so that user X is logged in.

Any ideas why?

```
url(r'^updateUser/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', views.updateUser.as_view(), \
            name='updateUser'),

class updateUser(UpdateView):
    model = User
```

I also try to override the get_object method and it didn't work

```
def get_object(self):
    obj = User.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['user_id'])
    return obj
```

Comment: Is this all of your view code? Pleaase show something more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `user` from the [`auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) context processor is clashing with the `user` from the view.

You can either access the logged in user with `{{ request.user }}` in your template.

Or you can set set [`context_object_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.context_object_name) to something else,

```
class UpdateUser(UpdateView):
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'user_to_update'
```

and access that user with `{{ user_to_update }}` in your template.

There's a ticket about this [25397](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25397).